# Apache Server-Status

Tags: apache-2.2

I am using Apache 2.2.24, and in that I am using more than 1 Vhosts.

My question is, while in server-status, can I filter it for one domain??

Is there any option??

like if I enter example.com/server-status, then it only shows example.com status, and if I enter another-example.com/server-status, then it shows only another-example.com Staus.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

As you can see in [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html), server-status hasn't so many configuration possibilities. You are using just one service, so there is one status for it. Apache hasn't got any connections per virtual host or something like that. You can just check info about running processes from one domain with something like:

`elinks -dump domain.tld/server-status | grep your-domain.tld`